# Python cannot stop a while loop in coroutine externally

Tags: python, process, web-crawler, python-asyncio

I want to dynamically control the spider from the outside such as add or stop a, How fix it?

as well as in process **class** definition **self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()** after start raise:

```
File "Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 102, in spawn_main
    source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess(
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Why?

My platform is Windows.

```
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process


class Spider(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stopped = False

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.fetching())

    async def fetching(self):
        while True:
            if self._stopped:  # not update variable
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                continue
            print("fetching...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True
        print('stop', self._stopped)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    s = Spider()
    s.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    s.stop()
```

the output is:

```
fetching...
fetching...
stop True
fetching...
fetching...
```

Comment: you run the `Spider` in another process, so changing the variable in the calling process won't affect it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a shared memory between those 2 processes (the main, and the one you created). Consider using [Value](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)

Fixed your code:

```
import asyncio
from ctypes import c_bool
from multiprocessing import Process, Value


class Spider(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stopped = Value(c_bool, False)  # <== here

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.fetching())

    async def fetching(self):
        while True:
            if self._stopped.value:  # <== here
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                continue
            print("fetching...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped.value = True  # <== here
        print('stop', self._stopped)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    s = Spider()
    s.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    s.stop()
```

But honestly, if you get the "stopped" value as True, you should `break` from the loop and not continue it forever.